# Xamarin iOS build seems to be running slower than usual

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

We are working on Xamarin forms project. For this we're using **Parse** as backend for our Xamarin forms project. We are using REST APIs to connect to the PARSE backend.
We are testing this app on both Android and iOS devices. **On iOS devices, the app is taking very long time to connect to REST APIs whereas the same code is working perfectly fine in android**. (in Android it takes less than 3 seconds, in iOS its more than 10 seconds for the same API call).

We are using Xamarin forms so the code base is common for iOS and Android.

We have recently updated to Xamarin studio version 5.9.7 (build 9) and after this update, above stated problem has appeared.

We've also posted the same question [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49768/xamarin-ios-build-seems-to-be-running-slower-than-usual#latest)

Could you please check and let us know if there is any known issue in new build?

Comment: Just wondering if you experienced this error after upgrading to version 5.9.7: 
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.  If so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

While it is very difficult to know exactly what is happening without a sample of the methodology you are using to connect, I can suggest that ModernHTTPClient (http://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient) for your HTTP calls, and this should improve performance greatly.

If you would like more detailed assistance, I would need to see some code of how you are handling your calls.

Thanks!